# Why does a non-empty List throw a Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java, android, list, listview, arraylist

I have an List array 'details'.

```
List<HistoryDetails> details
```

where HistoryDetails is an object containing strings.

When I check the size it gives me a positive value.

```
details.size()
```

But when I try to access an element it throws a null pointer exception.

```
details.get(0).getFirstElement();


Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.HistoryDetails.getFirstElement()' on a null object reference
```

I am invoking the element at the very next line to where I check the size. Hence, nothing should be reset. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A List `details` having many items can have first item a null object. before using that item check null.

```
if(details.get(0)!=null){
details.get(0).getFirstElement();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `details` is a `List`, but the first element of the `List` is null.  That is, it looks like `details.get(0) == null`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it contains null.

```
Log.d("TEST", details.get(0)); //should return null
```

Answer (score 0):

This will avoid the null pointer exception:

```
if (!details.isEmpty()) {
    details.get(0).getFirstElement();
}
```